# always available gpu servers

Tags: google-cloud-platform, quota, gpu

I need several GPU servers for rendering. Region doesn`t matter. Preemptible - I think it is ok for me. 
It is important that at any time I should be able to run a couple of instances with the GPU.

As I understand it, Google can take away quotas for gpu. Since the allocation of quotas in a few days, it is critical for me.
Moreover, according to the documentation:
"Quotas do not guarantee that resources will be available at all times. 
If a resource is not available, or if the region you choose is out of the resource, you will not be able to create new resources of that type, even if you have remaining quota in your region or project."

How can I build a project with Google that I could at any time to launch at least a couple of GPU servers in any region?

Answer (score 1):

To deploy an instance with GPU first you mush [upgrade your billing account](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#how-to-upgrade) and modify your region Quotas (don't forget the [global quota](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#gpus))

"When you request a GPU quota, you must request a quota for the GPU models that you want to create in each region, and an additional global quota for the total number of GPUs of all types in all zones."

Now on the subject to guarantee resources you will have to use [Compute Engine Reservations](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reserving-zonal-resources), don't forget to check "limitations and restrictions" section

Comment: Thank you for the answer!!!